Как поменять иероглифы при чтении файла на русские буквы?
У меня есть текстовый файл на русском языке. Я пишу код,который его прочитывает,но вместо русских букв я получаю это: РћРіРѕ,С‚РµРїРµСЂСЊ С‚СѓС‚ СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ Р±СѓРєРІС‹!
Как это исправить? Код представлен ниже:
text = 'E:/Pythonprojects/python learn/text/russian.txt'
with open(text) as file_object:
    read = file_object.read()
    
print(read)


https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626838/2752075 - вот это попробует.

где-то там у вас уже готовый utf8 перекодируется из cp1251 в utf8. вот и видите то, что видите. найдите и уберите описанную излишнюю перекодировку, и получится читабельный текст.

Попробуйте дописать кодировку в open:
with open(text, encoding="UTF-8") as file_object:

Помогло,спасибо большое! Буду знать :)
